# При установке расширений происходит понижение версии yii framework

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Передо мной стоит задача сделать асинхронную загрузку изображений на сайт. Для этого я планировал использовать следующие расширения:

1. FileInput Widget от Kartik Visweswaran (показано выше)
2. 2Amigos BlueImp File Uploader (обертка для BlueImp JQuery File Uploader)
   Но при установке данных расширений через composer происходит понижение версии фреймворка о чем мне сообщается :

Seems you have downgraded Yii Framework from version 2.0.21 to 2.0.17.

Как можно установить данные расширения?Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: а что в композер вы вводили? update? или install? И что написано в composer.json?

Comment: спасибо!!!проблему решил вот так в composer.json добавил :
"kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "dev-master"
и после этого сделал composer update